# Increase performance of Spark-job Collaborative Recommendation.

Tags: java, performance, machine-learning, apache-spark

This is my first Spark Application. I am using "ALS.train" for training the model - Model Factorization.  The total time that the Application takes is approx 45 mins.

Note: I think takeOrdered is the bottle neck. it takes 45ms per User for 60,000 Users.

1. What can I do further to increase its performance? (Decrease time mainly)
2. Am I missing any coding standard or guidelines that should be followed to write a multi threading Spark job.

Input Data Set

- Users: 60,000
- Product: 1,500

Output Data:

- Top 25 Products for each user.

Machine(only 1 Machine. Standalone Spark):

- 8 GB RAM
- 4 core Machine.

Total time being taken

- 45 Minutes (approx)

  ```
    private static void predict() {

          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

          logger.info("Model Trained with: ");
          logger.info("Data Count: {}",RATINGS_ALL.count());
          logger.info("Rank: {}",Constants.RANK);
          logger.info("Iterations: {}",Constants.NUMITERATION);
          logger.info("Lambda: {}",Constants.LAMBDA);

          model = ALS.train(JavaRDD.toRDD(RATINGS_ALL), Constants.RANK, Constants.NUMITERATION, Constants.LAMBDA);

          JavaRDD<Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Double>> tempRDD_ALL = RATINGS_ALL.map(ratingToUserProductTupRatingTup);
          JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Double> ALL_ORIGINAL = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(tempRDD_ALL).cache();
          JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> ALL_USERPRODUCT = RATINGS_ALL.map(ratingToUserProductTup).cache();
          logger.info("Total Error: {}",calculateError(ALL_ORIGINAL,ALL_USERPRODUCT));


          JavaRDD<Tuple1<Object>> userIds = RATINGS_ALL.map(ratingToUserTup).distinct();
          JavaRDD<Tuple1<Object>>[] arrayOfUsers = userIds.randomSplit(Constants.PARTITION);// 100 Partitions of 60,000 Users

          // Upto here it only takes 1 min. Code below takes 30 sec each for each partition. I have 100 Partitions. so (30*100)/60 ~ 50 mins.

          try {
              RESULT_PRINTWRITER = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Constants.RESULT_FILE, true)));
              int partitionCount = Constants.PARTITION.length;
              for (int i = 0; i < partitionCount; i++) {
                  JavaRDD<Tuple1<Object>> userId = arrayOfUsers[i].cache();
                  long st1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> userProducts = getCartesianProduct(userId); // Cartesian of 1% of userID with 1500 Products
                  logger.debug("Time in getting Cartesian: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - st1));// Takes 2ms
                  long st2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  JavaRDD<Rating> predictetRatingCV = model.predict(JavaRDD.toRDD(userProducts)).toJavaRDD().cache(); // Takes 2 seconds.
                  logger.debug("Time in predicting Values: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - st2));
                  List<Tuple1<Object>> userIDsas = userId.collect();

                  long st3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                  for (Tuple1<Object> obj : userIDsas) {
                      long st5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      List<Rating> ratings = predictetRatingCV.filter(new Function<Rating, Boolean>() {
                          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                          @Override
                          public Boolean call(Rating v1) throws Exception {
                              return v1.user() == ((Integer) obj._1).intValue();
                          }
                      }).cache().takeOrdered(25, decreasingComparator);
                      logger.trace("Time in getting Data in driver: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - st5)); // Take 45 ms each user.
                      long st4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      for (Rating r : ratings) {
                          RESULT_PRINTWRITER.println("ID_" + r.user() + "-" + r.product() + "," + r.user() + "," + r.product()
                                  + "," + r.rating());
                      }
                      logger.trace("Time in print Writer: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - st4)); // Takes 0 ms
                  }
                  logger.debug("Time in writing 1 Batch: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - st3)); // Takes 30 Seconds
                  logger.info("Prediction Done for {} percent users.", 100 * i / partitionCount);
              }
              RESULT_PRINTWRITER.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          logger.debug("Time in predicting Values: {}", getTimeString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
      }
  ```

Comment: You should break down you method into smaller methods, it's a pain to read the code.

Comment: I think takeOrdered is the bottle neck. it takes 45ms per User for 60,000 Users.